# Redirect customer to previous to previous page after login

Tags: magento2, customer-session

I want customers to get redirected to the page from they came from. For example

- Customer is on CMS page
- Goes to login page, logs in successfully
- Now I want user to get redirected to CMS page visited in first step

How can I do this. I tried changing login options configurations for customers in magento admin but did not serve my use case

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Stores** -> **Settings** -> **Configuration**.
From left menu go to **Customers** -> **Customer** **Configuration**.Under the Login Options
Set **Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in** to **No**.
Flush cache.
Make sure same value is set on store level.

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I have set the configuration to No,  and after I login it goes to customer/account page. I am using magento 2.4.2